# Set timeout not resetting div element colour programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to reset my div element to white after an onclick event, but have had little success. Any idea what is going wrong? It stays "stuck" on red.

```
$('.timeline-item').click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","#FFFFFF");
    }, 250);
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ya8vtnea/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, save reference to parent scope (`var _this = this`), because in your example `this` refers to `window`

```
$('.timeline-item').click(function() {
    var _this = this;

    $(this).css("background-color","red");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(_this).css("background-color","#FFFFFF");
    }, 250);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside the time out is not referring to the element which was clicked, instead `this` references the `window` object.

You can use a closure variable to hold the reference to the clicked element and then use it in the timeout handler

```
$('.timeline-item').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this).css("background-color","red");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.css("background-color","#FFFFFF");
    }, 250);
});
```